# BOOST: reference exported class with a string

Tags: c++, boost, import, export

currently I am registering and serializing some classes with Boost. Using the following code for each class:

```
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Namespace::ClassName)
```

Now my question is, is there a possible way to reference this class with the Namespace::ClassName so I can import/use/find the class again? So far my search in the Boost Documentation did not bear any results. Thanks

EDIT:

While trying the code from sehe the following error occurs:

Reason: A boost exception was raised: At /usr/include/boost/serialization/factory.hpp:38 in function T* boost::serialization::factory(__va_list_tag*) [with T = Namespace::ClassName; int N = 0] the following expression evaluted to false: false

Backtrace:

```
1       0x7fae7fbb7528 boost::assertion_failed(char const*, char const*, char const*, long) + 275
2             0x743147 Namespace::ClassName* boost::serialization::factory<Namespace::ClassName, 0>(__va_list_tag*) + 37
3             0x739bc5 boost::seri
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to piece this together from

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/serialization/doc/extended_type_info.html
- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/serialization/test/test_dll_plugin.cpp

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36c7d9dd9dafc3c5)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>

struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar&, unsigned) { }
};

struct MyStruct : Base {
    template <typename Ar> void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned) { ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Base>(*this); }
};

#if 1
    BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID(Base    , "98e8e3ea-a14a-4875-89d9-6dc58e10002c")
    BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID(MyStruct, "97e71ba2-8cb9-45b4-803f-809676925e5c")
#else
    BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Base)
    BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(MyStruct)
#endif

BOOST_SERIALIZATION_FACTORY_0(MyStruct)

int main() {
    using namespace boost::serialization;

    std::string s = guid<MyStruct>();
    std::cout << s << "\n";

    extended_type_info const* eti = extended_type_info::find(s.c_str());

    Base* p = static_cast<MyStruct*>(eti->construct());
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (!!p) << "\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
97e71ba2-8cb9-45b4-803f-809676925e5c
true
```

Or ([if you change `#if 1` to `#if 0`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c92d981378f1260a)):

```
MyStruct
true
```

Comment: This seems to work partly, as in i can find the extendet_type_info and it seems to evaluate correctly. 
Though while constructing the class i get a boost exception
 See edit in the question

Comment: For some reason, even though the factory is defined. it still uses the default case, which by implementation does nothing. Hence i get the message, that the expression is evaluated to false.

Comment: Can you show me the SSCCE of that failing? See also **[Nobody Writes Testcases Anymore](http://kera.name/articles/2013/10/nobody-writes-testcases-any-more/)** and **[Solve your problem by almost asking a question on Stackoverflow](http://blog.jerryorr.com/2014/04/solve-your-problem-by-almost-asking.html)**.

Comment: Had to reposition the factory into the same class as the export. Am working on more than one class. It is working now!